# Add additional initializing arguments for forms.Form __init__

Tags: django, django-forms

I am creating a form and want to add a dynamic argument as following:

```
from django import forms

def get_quantity_choices(avail_qty):
    return  [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, avail_qty)]

class QuantityForm(forms.Form):
    
    def __init__(self, request, avail_qty, *args, **kwargs):
        self.avail_qty_choices = get_quantity_choices(avail_qty)
        
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(
                                choices=avail_qty_choices,
                                coerce=int)
```

so that I could do this

```
form = QuantityForm(request.POST, available_quantity)
```

where `available_quantity` is a variable dynamically generated elsewhere in my app.

But I keep getting this error message "Undefined name avail_qty_choices" .

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the `choices` work. The class attributes are intialized when the class is interpreted, when you start the server. The fact that it appears under the `__init__` method is not relevant.

You can let the super constructor do the work, and then alter the choices of the `quantity` field. Initially you can set the choices for example to an empty list:

```
from django import forms

class QuantityForm(forms.Form):

    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=[], coerce=int)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, avail_qty=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['quantity'].choices = get_quantity_choices(avail_qty)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your recommended way. It works. But setting the
```self.fields['quantity'].choices = get_quantity_choices(avail_qty)``` gives me an error ```int object has no attribute 'get'```. 
But changing to this works 
```self.fields['quantity'] = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices = get_quantity_choices(avail_qty),
                                                        coerce=int)```